# iOS/Swift postiion of all objects in viewController is reset after .setBackgroundImage

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

As described in the title, for some reason the position of all objects that have been moved is reset to its original position after `.setBackgroundImage` is called on some `UIButton`.

The original position of UI elements is set via StoryBoard after that I am changing the position of some elements using PanGestureRecognizer (For example menu slides up)

Simple like that:

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
if let view = recognizer.view {
view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
                        y:view.center.y + translation.y)
}
recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}
```

After that I have some button with background picture which is changed when user chooses theme change, .setBackgroundImage is preformed on this UIButton like this:

```
button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
```

After the image is changed on the button the position of translated object (menu that is slid up) is set back to its original position set via storyboard I want this menu to stay open even after image on some none related button is changed.

Comment: Based on your question, I would assume that you already have some code! please provide it to the viewers...

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you are doing.

Comment: Please provide some code, as per your description it seems that it's auto layout issue. Set your button height and width as fix width and height.

Comment: Basicaly i am moving objects with PanGestures , i have one button wich changes its background image on click , if this is triggered all other objects are returned to original positions before they were moved with pan gestures.